# How to select Tweet button Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm just refreshing my WebDriver skills and am trying to automate sending a tweet in Java.  I can login and click on on 'Tweet'.  After selecting this, a modal dialog pop up appears.  The tweet button is disabled until typing at least 1 character in the box, after which is is enabled:

`<button class="btn primary-btn tweet-action tweet-btn js-tweet-btn" type="button">`

But I cannot seem to select it with any selector.  I guess I need to somehow switch driver control to the modal dialog but not sure how.  It is not within a frame.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for the longest time. I wouldn't be surprised if Twitter made this impossible as a matter of principle.

Answer (score 1):

After you've selected `global-tweet-box` and sent the appropriate keys, do this, because Twitter has a feature whereby pressing CTRL + RETURN (or ENTER) will actually fire off the tweet once the modal box is open and populated with text:

```
String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
driver.findElement(By.id("tweet-box-global")).sendKeys(selectAll);
```

**The full code should looks like this:**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("global-new-tweet-button")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("tweet-box-global")).click();
String keys = "This is my first automated tweet.";
driver.findElement(By.id("tweet-box-global")).sendKeys(keys);

String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.RETURN);
driver.findElement(By.id("tweet-box-global")).sendKeys(selectAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

Function Modal Dialog Box is used to deal with Modal Type Windows.
When we open a window using this function Java-script execution gets suspended till the window gets closed.
Here parent window is expecting some return value from the pop-up window.
So the problem in Selenium Web-driver is that when we open a Modal window then accessibility to the parent window is Blocked.

**Problem in Selenium with Modal Dialog Box:**
Selenium works with Java-script. When show Modal dialog is called Javascript gets suspended from the parent.
Selenium whose handle still pointing to the Main window gets suspended.
As a result all the successive commands after that gets suspended.

**How to handle Modal Dialog Box in Selenium Web-driver.** 
Pre-requisite: I believe when a Modal Dialog Box is opened then the cursor is on the Modal Dialog Box.
In that case we can handle the operation on the Modal Dialog Box using Robot class.

After we perform the action which opens Modal Dialog box, Try below Method

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    StringSelection data_to_enter= new StringSelection("Data to Enter");
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(data_to_enter, null); 
    Thread.sleep(7000);  
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V); 
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V); 
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Information is handful. But, this is no case of a modal dialog box. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code. It works. **(Assuming you've coded the part of clicking on the button that opens up the dialog box for tweeting)** . **And, for the record, the dialog box is within the top window only. There are no frame(s) involved.**

```
//For adding content in the message box, i.e, "Hello"
driver.findElement(By.id("tweet-box-global")).sendKeys("Hello");

//Clicking on the Tweet button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@class='t1-form tweet-form']//div[@class='tweet-button']/button")).click();
```

Comment: Please do care to add a reason in comments section when negative voting any answer. This is a valid answer and it did work. Say, if it didn't, I don't see the point why it should be negatively voted.

Answer (score -1):

After entering some text in the text field, the Tweet button will be enabled and you will be able to click on it using following which uses css for the button:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.primary-btn.tweet-action.tweet-btn.js-tweet-btn")).click();
```